# Hello OS with C# & mono?

Tags: .net, mono

Is there a way to identify in which OS we are running mono, with C# code?

Some sort of Hello World, but instead of using a fixed string as an output use the current OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `System.Environment.OSVersion`

You can also detect if your code is run under Mono or MS.NET:

```
if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null) 
{
    // we're on Mono
    IsMono = true;
} 
else
    IsMono = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, Environment.OSVersion indeed returns which OS I am running.

Comment: If your code might run on really old Mono, remember that it used 128 as PlatformID for Unix.

Answer (score 3):

This link: http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical#How_to_detect_the_execution_platform_.3F

Give this code:

using System;

```
class Program {

    static void Main ()
    {
            int p = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
            if ((p == 4) || (p == 6) || (p == 128)) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Running on Unix");
            } else {
                    Console.WriteLine ("NOT running on Unix");
            }
    }
}
```