# Determine hard drive serial number in mono?

Tags: c#, mono, hardware, uniqueidentifier, serial-number

I am developing a library in C# that generates a unique hardware ID using these 3 variables

1. Machine name
2. MAC address
3. Hard drive serial number

I am able to get the machine name and MAC address in both .NET and Mono but I can only get the hard drive serial number in .NET. Does anyone know if there is any possible way to get the hard drive serial number in mono or should I just use another variable (ie: CPU name, Motherboard ID, etc)?

Comment: Note that both the machine name and MAC address can manually be set, so they are not really unique.

Comment: A GUID is based off the MAC address...

Comment: And a MAC address can be spoofed: http://osxdaily.com/2008/01/17/how-to-spoof-your-mac-address-in-mac-os-x/  You can not assume it is unique to a specific Ethernet interface on a specific computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://www.crosstwinkle.com/drminfodoc/html/DRMInfo.htm):

> Mac OS X doesn't support getting hard disk serial number from user-level application

If the requirement to be root on mac is not a problem for you (or you skip the mac version), I have one brute way to solve the problem:

Using [this article](http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical#How_to_detect_the_execution_platform_.3F) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692410/hello-os-with-c-sharp-mono) question you can determine:

1. Are you running Mono or .NET
2. Which platform are you on

If you know you are on the LINUX system, you can get hardrive serial through [running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) such [system command](https://serverfault.com/questions/305205/linux-hard-drive-serial-number-as-non-root):

```
/sbin/udevadm info --query=property --name=sda
```

On mac you can use [Disk Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility) (as root) to get harddrive serial. On windows you can use the standard approach.

Comment: Thanks! I might have to revert to a different variable for the unique identifier cause of MAC OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it also with user permission with ioreg

from a shell:

ioreg -p IOService -n AppleAHCIDiskDriver -r|grep \"Serial Number\"|awk '{print $NF;}'

programmatically:

```
    uint GetVolumeSerial(string rootPathName)
    {
        uint volumeSerialNumber = 0;
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "/usr/sbin/ioreg";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.Arguments = "-p IOService -n AppleAHCIDiskDriver -r -d 1";
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process p = Process.Start(psi);
        string output;
        do
        {
            output = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            int idx = output.IndexOf("Serial Number");
            if (idx != -1)
            {
                int last = output.LastIndexOf('"');
                int first = output.LastIndexOf('"', last - 1);
                string tmp = output.Substring(first + 1, last - first - 1);
                volumeSerialNumber = UInt32.Parse(tmp);
                break;
            }
        } while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream);
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();
        return volumeSerialNumber;
    }
```